# MultiDataTrigger conditions null check

Tags: wpf

I am trying to setup a grid's visibility using a multidatatrigger. The condition for making it visible is PropertyA==null && PropertyB==false. I am not sure how PropertyA condition is to be written. My attempt is here (but not working):

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding PropertyA}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding PropertyB}" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
```

Could someone advise pls.

Comment: Change `Control` to `Grid`. So rather than `Control.Visibility` use `Grid.Visibility` or set TargetType in your Style tag.

Comment: thanks. But this does not fix it

Comment: OK, how about Binding errors do you get any? Another possibility is that you have this in a `DataTemplate` or `ControlTemplate`? Could you post how you use this `Grid`? i.e. is it directly in your `Window` or `UserControl`?

Comment: It is directly under my usercontrol. There are no binding errors. Is the condition for PropertyA correct. Does Value="{x:Null}" comparison work here ? or I need to use a NulltoBooleanConverter ?

Comment: I used `{x:Null}` in my app and it worked perfectly fine. The only thing I can think of here is that either data is NOT null, it might be an empty string?

Comment: do you have any control inside your Grid @Awadhesh? try setting some height to the grid. This code is fine. It should work

Comment: @AwadheshPratap have you had a chance to test my answer?

Comment: @AwadheshPratap your code is alright, what are you trying to see my setting the visibility of Grid. it's just a arrangement on UI, it doesn't have any visual. hopefully you have other controls in your grid. try to set the style on those elements instead of grid.

Answer (score 0):

This is the style that I have used, it is for Button but it works as expected

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnTakePhoto">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Comment}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ResponseNumber}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Try to take the Style out of your Grid and include it in your `UserControl.Resources` tag.
You would use it like so:
`<Button Style="{StaticResource btnTakePhoto}"/>`
There is absolutely no reason for your xaml not to work.
**EDIT**
Also I have this code in my other `UserControl`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnShowHide, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
<ToggleButton MinHeight="150" Width="50" Content=">" Name="btnShowHide">
```